# Add one to file name?

Tags: rename

I have 100 files which I have to rename by adding one to each file as shown here:

```
CIR14_8233.tif
CIR14_8234.tif
CIR14_8235.etc
etc
```

They have to be renamed in accordance with their time stamp such that the first file is the oldest.

I have total commander or commandline in order to do this? Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Windows 7